# How do I make navbar fixed/sticky? position: fixed, sticky not working

Tags: html, css

How do I make navbar fixed/sticky? position: fixed, sticky not working.

Html

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header">
            <div>
                <img id="fc-logo" src="https://pwa-cdn.freecharge.in/pwa-static/pwa/images/header/fc-logo.svg" alt="freecharge logo" height="70" width="200">
            </div>
            <div>
                <i class="login-icon fa fa-user-circle fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p id="login">Login/Register</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

css

```
.header{
    position:sticky;
    top: 0;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; there already are some suggested answers. Here's the documentation of postion:sticky: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky - which speaks of "nearest scrolling ancestor" and "container block", so the <header> styling may be influencing you desired outcome. My 2¢ worth.

Answer (score 0):

```
.header{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    width:"100%";
    min-height:"8vh";
}
```

Comment: While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem. See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Before you check for other issues, it might be a good idea to ensure that you're using a browser that supports `position: sticky`.

I am suggesting you `top` as extra parameter because
a sticky element requires a `threshold` to be specified, which means that you must set a value other than `"auto"` for at least one of the following properties:

`top`
or
`right`
or
`bottom`
or
`left`

For more details visit [Here](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-fix-issues-with-css-position-sticky-not-working)

```
.navbar {
   position : sticky;
    top : 0;
  background-color: #32839c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code! change `flex-direction: row` and remove child padding if you want a horizontal item menu. Thanks :)

```css
*,*::before,*::after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
   height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background: grey;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header>div:first-child {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.header>div:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header">
            <div>
                <img id="fc-logo" src="https://pwa-cdn.freecharge.in/pwa-static/pwa/images/header/fc-logo.svg" alt="freecharge logo" height="70" width="200">
            </div>
            <div>
                <i class="login-icon fa fa-user-circle fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p id="login">Login/Register</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```